# How can I limit the minimum zoom in a React Native pinch to zoom animation?

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-gesture-handler

I implemented a pinch to zoom component in React Native using the react-native-gesture-handler and Animated module from react-native. How can I limit the zoom to never scale the image to a size smaller than 1.0x?

Here is a stripped down version of my code.

As you can see, I mapped the scale parameter from the nativeevent to the Animated Value called currZoomScale. The purpose of the math in this code is to begin a pinch gesture at the zoom scale at which the previous pinch gesture ended.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { State, HandlerStateChangeEvent, PinchGestureHandler, PinchGestureHandlerEventPayload } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

const SIZE = Dimensions.get('window').width
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  imageStyle: {
    height: SIZE,
    width: SIZE
  },
  zoomScrollContainer: {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})

export const ZoomableComponent: React.FC<ZoomableComponentProps> = () => {
  const [zoomedImageUri, setZoomedImageUri] = React.useState('')

  let _zoomScale: number
  let _tempZoomScale: number = 1

  const prevZoomScale = new Animated.Value(1)
  const currZoomScale = new Animated.Value(1)
  const zoomScale = Animated.multiply(prevZoomScale, currZoomScale)
  const tempZoomScale = new Animated.Value(1)

  zoomScale.addListener(({ value }) => {
    _zoomScale = value
  })
  tempZoomScale.addListener(({ value }) => {
    _tempZoomScale = value
  })
  const onPinchEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: { scale: currZoomScale },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }
  )
  const onPinchStateChange = ((event: HandlerStateChangeEvent<PinchGestureHandlerEventPayload>) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.BEGAN) {
      // We start this pinch event with the scale value that the previous pinch event ended with.
      prevZoomScale.setValue(_tempZoomScale)
      currZoomScale.setValue(1)
    }

    // Rather than check if state = END, we check if the previous state was ACTIVE. 
    // This way we include all events that are in an END, CANCELED or FAILED state.
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      // We remember the ending scale value when the pinch event ends
      tempZoomScale.setValue(_zoomScale)
    }
  })

  const changeImage = ((uri: string) => {
    setZoomedImageUri(uri)
  })

    return (
      <View>
        <PinchGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={onPinchEvent}
          onHandlerStateChange={onPinchStateChange}
        >
              <Animated.View >
                <Animated.Image
                  source={{ uri: zoomedImageUri }}
                  style={[styles.imageStyle, {
                    transform: [
                      { scale: zoomScale }
                    ]
                  }
                  ]}
                >
                </Animated.Image>
              </Animated.View>
        </PinchGestureHandler>
      </View>
    )
}
```